# Check if two time objects are on the same Date in Go

Tags: date, time, go

What is the best way to compare two `time.Time` objects to see if they are on the same calendar day?

I looked at using `t.Truncate()` but it can only truncate to hours. I know I can use `t.GetDate()` which is straightforward but still requires more lines of code than I think should be necessary.

Comment: Couldn't you just pass `24*time.Hour` to `Truncate`?

Comment: Yes, but only if you are using a timezone with no daylight savings time. Days are not always 24 hours.

Comment: days are almost never exactly 24 hours long

Comment: Are both times in the same timezone? If not, you need to be careful about what "on the same calendar day" means.

Comment: In this case they are the same timezone, but that is a good point.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's inefficient to parse the time for the date components three times by making separate method calls for the year, month, and day. Use a single method call for all three date components. From my benchmarks, it's nearly three times faster. For example,

```
import "time"

func DateEqual(date1, date2 time.Time) bool {
    y1, m1, d1 := date1.Date()
    y2, m2, d2 := date2.Date()
    return y1 == y2 && m1 == m2 && d1 == d2
}
```

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but would this not also compare the actual time, like hours and seconds instead of just they day, month and year?

Comment: it would not actually, check this out: https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Date, the Date() function will only return the year, month and day from the timestamp

Comment: Note: This does not account for times with different timezones. For example one time at 6pm ET will not equal a UTC timestamp for 7pm ET (which would be midnight UTC). You have to make sure you first convert both times to the same timezone first.

Answer (score 11):

```
if a.Day() == b.Day() && a.Month() == b.Month() && a.Year() == b.Year() {
    // same date
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can truncate to days too, by using:

```
t.Truncate(time.Hour * 24)
```

Comment: Apparently only works on UCT time, because _it states in the Truncate() doc, that the calculation is performed "since the zero time", and in the Time type docs that "The zero value of type Time is January 1, year 1, 00:00:00.000000000 UTC."_
according to [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25254593/2399562)

Answer (score 1):

Another way around this is to get the string representation of dates from both times and compare them:

```golang
func sameDay(date, another time.Time) bool {
    return date.Format(time.DateOnly) == another.Format(time.DateOnly)
}
```