# How do I take minutes and hours from time.Now() function

Tags: go

I am doing program for one of checking I need real time in minutes like if its 10:00 I should have 600 minutes

I tried using time.Now() function and .Hour and .Minute and it works but sadly when it comes to ParseDuration to get minutes of hours I get these errors :
go:91:4: assignment mismatch: 1 variable but time.ParseDuration returns 2 values
go:91:25: cannot use hours (type func() int) as type string in argument to time.ParseDuration

```
now := time.Now()
hours := (now.Hour)
minutes := (now.Minute)
m := time.ParseDuration(hours)
```

I expect get real time in minutes as integer that i could use in my if statements and cycles

Comment: `Hour` is a function, and so is `Minute`. To get the actual value, call those functions, don't assing them.

Comment: So I need make 3 functions one for Time.Now, Hour and Minute and then call them to my function ?

Comment: You can use `(now.Hour() * 60) + now.Minute()` to get 600 if it's 10:00, no need to pass the result to `ParseDuration`.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/v6kcR7Mq80-

Answer (score 2):

First, convert your time object to an interval. It sounds like what you care about is hours/minutes since midnight, so refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25254443/13860) to calculate midnight for your local time, or UTC, whichever you care about.  Then determine the duration since midnight, the you can easily use the `Hours` or `Minutes` methods on the [Duration](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) type.

Putting it all together:

```
midnight := time.Now().Truncate(24 * time.Hour) // or similar, depending on exact needs
dur := time.Since(midnight)
hours := dur.Hours()
mins := dur.Minutes()
```

Note that `Hours()` and `Minutes()` return floats, not integers. If you need integers, do your own conversion.

The `time.Time` object also has the `Hour` and `Minute` methods, which may do what you want, but they give less control when it comes to timezone handling.

```
now := time.Now()
hour := now.Hour()
min := now.Minute()
```

Comment: To be explicit: [Time.Truncate does not produce local midnight outside of UTC](https://play.golang.org/p/qTZwz-gKgxw). You have to decide if the intended result is what a continuously running stopwatch would show, or if it's what you would naively infer from a clock on the wall: https://play.golang.org/p/UUMHJJIPo-B